# Read a String as HTML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have been searching for a while but I can't find information that help me.

I have this string variable that has a bunch of HTML in it (tags, text and links to images too) and I want to know how to convert that string into some kind of HTML supported type to show in my app, so that it appears with the images and the text in bold instead of just plain text with tags everywhere.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <h2>
      <img src="https://www.iseg.ulisboa.pt/aquila/getFile.do?method=getFile&amp;fileId=682501" alt="" width="745" height="497" />
    </h2>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>
            <a href="https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=21016A3C1649D3A2!4589&amp;authkey=!ACVZ-u-igsIFDLs&amp;ithint=folder%2cjpg">&gt;&nbsp;Reportagem Fotográfica (7 de Março)</a>
            <br /> 
            <a href="https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=21016A3C1649D3A2!4738&amp;authkey=!AJbBcUJpWxqtP3g&amp;ithint=folder%2cjpg">&gt; Reportagem Fotográfica (9 de Março)</a></h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h6>Decorrem nos dias 7 e 9 de Março as Cerimónias de Entrega de Diplomas de Pós-Graduação, no Auditório CGD.
            <br />Contaram com momentos musicais de Manuel Rebelo e João Gil. Mais uma vez, parabéns a todos os diplomados!</h6>
            <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What framework are you using? ASP.NET MVC? WebForms?

Comment: How does "this string variable that has a bunch of HTML in it" looks like?

Comment: have you tried Nuget HTML Renderer for WinForms?

Comment: @reporter changed the question for you. I want to show that in my app without the tags obviously but with the characteristics each of them give to  the text like the tables and images

Answer (score 2):

You could likely use the [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control to handle this and then explicitly set it's contents to your HTML string via the `NavigateToString()` method :

```
// Set your HTML content for your web browser
YourWebBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlString);
```

If that didn't work for your needs, you could resort to using a third-party control like [this HtmlRenderer available via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.WPF), which sounds like it might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I would use it but when I try to install the packages it always fails